# (java)Could not find the main class

Tags: jvm, java

My code is compiled on OSX and it works fine(compiler version 1.6). But when I copy it to a remote ubuntu. I can not run it.

When I run

> java TPCC.class

I got exception like this.(By the way TPCC.class is in default package)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TPCC/class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TPCC.class
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: TPCC.class.  Program will exit.
```

And my java version on ubuntu:

```
java version "1.6.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_21-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 17.0-b16, mixed mode, sharing)
```

It's also 1.6 and I think it fits the compiled binary. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Try `java TPCC`, not `java TPCC.class`

Comment: As indicated by phs the invocation command seems to be the problem, it looks like it is simply not in the class path and there are no version problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the way you run the program. Compiled java called

> ClassName.java

will be ClassName.class. You should run it like

> "java ClassName"

. You shouldn't run it as

> "java ClassName.class"

What happens here is this. When you run it as java ClassName.class, JVM try to look for ClassName called "class" in the package called "ClassName" that does not exist. So it will throw NoClassDefFoundError.

Answer (score 0):

This is an invocation problem as the error shows: java  should be used and not the filename of the class.
The error message tries to say you this by stating that "TPCC/class" is not found.

(sorry for first adding comment, used the wrong field)

Answer (score 0):

Specify the classpath when invoking java:

```
java -cp <path-to-jar> TPCC
```